# GMAIL API : How to get the reply without the original message

Tags: gmail-api

i'm using google api for gmail. All is working fine, i was able to connect, list and get message / thread, browse every elements of a thread etc...

I want to be able to retrieve a reply without the original message, is it somehow doable ?

I think that every email software will put together a different constructed reply message with the original message included but maybe there's a way to retrieve only the reply.

Thanks for any hint that will allow me to do such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the consensus is that [this is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439613/gmail-api-how-to-get-the-reply-message-without-the-original-message), and that the message/thread must be parsed manually with your program.

Comment: You're right. I'll delete my answer since I misunderstood the original question. It will only confuse people.

Comment: It's a shame that google didn't manage to offer us this possibility. It didn't seems to complicated at their level to store each individual message in parralel of the all thread.