# Get only a particular message in Gmail API

Tags: api, gmail, gmail-api

So what I am trying to do is get the messages from my Gmail account, through Gmail API, but the message am getting is appened with the message to with which it is replied to.

What is happening : (example message)

Done.

Do let me know what you think of the same.

Regards
ABC

On Friday, January 8, 2016, John Doe  wrote:
I thought this was done earlier? 
On 08-Jan-2016, at 5:01 pm, ABC  wrote:

Please let us know who I can talk to about having this done.

Regards,

### ABC

What I want :

Done.

Do let me know what you think of the same.

Regards,
ABC

Comment: That's the way Gmail works I'm afraid. The original message is actually a part of actual response, so you have to remove it yourself. There are [ways to remove it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439613/how-to-get-the-reply-message-without-the-original-message-from-the-gmail-api), but it's tricky to make it work for all types of messages.

Comment: @Tholle can you recommend some more tactics to do this?

Comment: @devpro I am afraid there is no code to show because I am still exploring this functionality from GMAIL API reference.

Comment: @RahulDhawani Sorry, I have never had to do it myself, so I don't know :(

Comment: Depending on the App you are trying to build - you could access this through the Gmail UI when in Conversation mode.  You could use something like InboxSDK to access the body or scrape the DOM.  If you are not looking at using something like a Chrome extension for your app then this will not be appropriate.

Comment: Another thought - you could compare messages from within a thread - that way you will know where the new part of the message starts/end.

Comment: @PNC Thanks a lot! This was some light in darkness.

Answer (score 0):

I only manage to get rid of those in Java by modifying the HTML message I received using org.jsoup.Jsoup manipulations. This is snipped from existing code, so hope I did not forget something:

```
final Document doc = Jsoup.parse(gmail_message);

// Remove first gmail_quote div if exists, to clean up long threads.
if (null != doc.select("div.gmail_quote").first())
{
   doc.select("div.gmail_quote").first().remove();
}

// Remove any inline images from message as they are included as attachments
while (null != (doc.select("img[src^=cid:]").first())
{
   doc.select("img[src^=cid:]").first().remove();
}

// We remove any scripts in message
while (null != doc.select("script").first())
{
   doc.select("script").first().remove();
}

// We remove any iframes
while (null != doc.select("iframe").first())
{
   doc.select("iframe").first().remove();
}

message_text.setValue(doc.toString());
```

I have not seen any inline messages for awhile except from non Gmail users which is rare. And I got rid of those pesky inline images as well. As you see I went a little bananas here and removed scripts and iframes as well. Meh. ;)

I hope that helps in some way.