# Android Gmail api support to check if user replied to the mail

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I am developing an Android application in which I need to show how many mails the user has not replied to (based on a particular sender/subject).

Is this is feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't particularly dabbled in GMail API but as per googling and looking around the community for a while, I think it seems feasible. I think you could make use of [labels](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels) and [threads](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/threads). As per `threads` docs:

> The Gmail API uses Thread resources to group email replies with their original message into a single conversation or thread. This allows you to retrieve all messages in a conversation, in order, making it easier to have context for a message or to refine search results.

I think you can just tweak around it, like to get the most recent message in a thread, then check if it was sent by the user, then just return true or false as the identifier. Here's a post that's about [retrieving the reply of a message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31439613/6124253), might be useful. Code and logic is still up to you though.